# generate a plot based on time-delta value

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, visualization

I have data frame which captures the data sent from the server. the server data at least once in 5 minutes. if the server doesn't send data for more than 5 minutes that time till the data is sent again is considered as black-out. I want to visualize these blackouts in a graph. The data frame looks like

```
timestamp                   temperature
2019-06-03 14:16:31.149132  27.17
2019-06-03 14:21:34.732911  27.13
2019-06-03 14:37:20.437143  27.16
2019-06-03 14:42:15.516416  27.13
2019-06-03 14:51:26.167553  27.19
2019-06-03 14:56:31.244862  27.02
2019-06-03 15:07:30.519727  27.1
2019-06-03 15:12:57.319953  27.12
2019-06-03 15:17:56.256638  27.12
```

I have calculated  the time difference between two time stamps and, marked blackout and calculated the blackout time. 
code:

```
df['TimeDelta'] = df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift()
df['blackout'] = np.where(df['TimeDelta'] > datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5) , 1 , 0)
df['blackoutTime'] =  np.where(df['blackout'] > 0, df['TimeDelta'] - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5), 0)
df['blackoutMins'] = df['blackoutTime'] / np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

which gives 4 additional columns

```
TimeDelta               blackout  blackoutIime           blackoutMins
0 days 00:04:57.310512000   0   0 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.0
0 days 00:05:03.583779000   1   0 days 00:00:03.583779000   0.05972965
0 days 00:15:45.704232000   1   0 days 00:10:45.704232000   10.7617372
0 days 00:04:55.079273000   0   0 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.0
0 days 00:09:10.651137000   1   0 days 00:04:10.651137000   4.17751895
0 days 00:05:05.077309000   1   0 days 00:00:05.077309000   0.08462181666666667
0 days 00:10:59.274865000   1   0 days 00:05:59.274865000   5.9879144166666665
0 days 00:05:26.800226000   1   0 days 00:00:26.800226000   0.44667043333333334
0 days 00:04:58.936685000   0   0 days 00:00:00.000000000   0.0
0 days 00:05:16.684317000   1   0 days 00:00:16.684317000   0.27807195
0 days 00:05:02.304786000   1   0 days 00:00:02.304786000   0.0384131
```

So what i want i am trying is to visualize the blackouts with time on x-axis and blackout on the y-axis, i want something like 
[image]

with x-axis being the time axis and y -axis showing the time for which its blackout. Can someone help with how to do this visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `plt.step` against the original `timestamp`:

```
df['blackout'] = df.timestamp.diff().gt('5min').astype(int)

plt.step(df.timestamp, df.blackout, c='red')
```

Output:

[image]